# pandas datetimeindex: get dates in this index that are <= given date

Tags: pandas

How can one get the list of dates in a datetimeindex that are less or equal to a given date?

What kind of slicing to do?

I have tried to [ index < date ] without success,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a series and the index is sorted (it should be) just do:

```
mySeries[:myDateString]
```

This is very clearly demnostrated in the documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing

If the index isn't sorted, just use logical indexing:

```
mySeries[mySeries.index < myTimeStamp]
```

Comment: but that is on the series object.... what about if I have a datetimeindex object only

Comment: I see DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time() but there is no similar function for dates.

Comment: @MMM, honestly, i'd just stuff it in a Series.